# mail invite is not working in my thunderbird

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, thunderbird

I am using Thunderbird 31.1.1.
Whenever i get a mail of type invitation(like meeting or something at some time),my body of the mail is not displayed properly.
It displays as shown below.

```
  BEGIN:VCALENDAR
  PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 15.0 MIMEDIR//EN
  VERSION:2.0
  METHOD:REQUEST
  X-MS-OLK-FORCEINSPECTOROPEN:TRUE
  BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
  TZID:Central Standard Time
  BEGIN:STANDARD
  DTSTART:16011104T020000
  RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=1SU;BYMONTH=11
  TZOFFSETFROM:-0500
  TZOFFSETTO:-0600
  END:STANDARD
  BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
  DTSTART:16010311T020000
  RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=2SU;BYMONTH=3
  TZOFFSETFROM:-0600
  TZOFFSETTO:-0500
  END:DAYLIGHT
  END:VTIMEZONE
  BEGIN:VEVENT
  ATTENDEE;CN="";RSVP=TRUE:
  ATTENDEE;CN="";RSVP=TRUE:mailto:
  ATTENDEE;CN=;RSVP=TRUE:mailto:
  ATTENDEE;CN="''";RSVP=TRUE:mailto:
  CLASS:PUBLIC
  CREATED:20140919T065509Z
  DESCRIPTION:
  DTEND;TZID="Central Standard Time":20140919T090000
  DTSTAMP:20140919T065509Z
  DTSTART;TZID="Central Standard Time":20140919T083000
  LAST-MODIFIED:20140919T065509Z
  LOCATION:Phone Conference
  ORGANIZER;CN=Rahul:mailto:
  PRIORITY:5
  RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR
  SEQUENCE:0
  SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en-in:
  TRANSP:OPAQUE
  UID:040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E0080000000070FE7EE6FED3CF01000000000000000
  0100000001F203614BE188A48BF3B7FD3D772C111
 X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=
 X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:TENTATIVE
 X-MICROSOFT-CDO-IMPORTANCE:1
 X-MICROSOFT-CDO-INTENDEDSTATUS:BUSY
 X-MICROSOFT-DISALLOW-COUNTER:FALSE
 X-MS-OLK-AUTOSTARTCHECK:FALSE
 X-MS-OLK-CONFTYPE:0
 BEGIN:VALARM
 TRIGGER:-PT15M
 ACTION:DISPLAY
 DESCRIPTION:Reminder
 END:VALARM
 END:VEVENT
 END:VCALENDAR
```

Are there any settings to view it properly.
Please advice.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have the Lightning extension installed?  Thunderbird is an email client and doesn't understand calendar invites natively.

Answer (score 0):

Please install "Lighting" add on.
This works.
http://smallbusiness.chron.com/receive-outlook-invitations-thunderbird-55866.html